# Getting dots to render on line chart d3 (Doing this in Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js

UPDATE: So, I was able to get the data into my cx/cy data properly (spits out the correct values), but the element gives me an error of NaN.

So I get 3 circle elements with only the radius defined.

Original post:

I have a question about rendering dots in on a d3 line chart. I will try to give every part of the relevant code (and the data structure, which is slightly more complicated).

So, currently, 1 black dot renders in the top left corner of my chart, but nowhere else. It looks like I am getting 3 constants when I console.log the cx and cy return functions. What am I doing wrong?

Cities is currently an array that returns 3 objects.

Each object has the following structure:

```
Object {
 name: 'string',
 values: array[objects]
}
```

values array is as follows:

```
objects {
 Index: number,
 Time: date in a particular format
}
```

Okay. Relevant code time:

```
      var points = svg.selectAll('dot')
        .data(cities);



      console.log('Points is :', points)


        points
        .enter().append('circle')
        // .data(function(d) {console.log("data d is :", d); return d})
        .data(cities)
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
          return x(new Date(d.values.forEach(function(c) {
            console.log("cx is: ", c.Time);
            return c.Time;
          })))})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
          return y(d.values.forEach(function(c) {
            console.log("cy is: ", c.Index)
            return c.Index;
          }))
        })
        .attr('r', dotRadius());



      points.exit().remove();

      // points.attr('class', function(d,i) { return 'point point-' + i });

      d3.transition(points)
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
          return x(new Date(d.values.forEach(function(c) {
            console.log("cx is: ", c.Time);
            return c.Time;
          })))})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
          return y(d.values.forEach(function(c) {
            console.log("cy is: ", c.Index)
            return c.Index;
          }))
        })
        .attr('r', dotRadius())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested selection here.

This:

```
.attr('cx', function(d) {
  return x(new Date(d.values.forEach(function(c) {
    console.log("cx is: ", c.Time);
    return c.Time;
})))})
```

is totally invalid.  One, `attr` is expecting a single value to set, you are trying to get it to process an array of values.  Two, `forEach` by design only returns *undefined*.  Just not going to work.

You should be doing something like this:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".groupOfPoint") //<-- top level selection
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "groupOfPoint");

  g.selectAll(".point") //<-- this is the nested selection
    .data(function(d){
      return d.values; //<-- we are doing a circle for each value
    })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr('cx', function(d){
      return x(d.Time);
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d){
      return y(d.Index);
    })
    .attr('r', 5)
    .style('fill', function(d,i,j){
      return color(j);
    });
```

Since you seem to be building off of this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955), I've [modified it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Ysge0K79zj7VUEiZw7A?p=preview) to be a scatter plot instead of line.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem. My data was too high level.

I'll keep this in mind when I'm working with more complicated data structures. I did actually use that example to get around the problem I had (IE, I wanted to separate the lines of my data based on columns), but my data structure is very, very different :)